# show and hide dialog in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am having a situation that my dialog doesn't show up in my asyncTask.
The codes below are my asyncTask

```
private class AsyncCallListWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "--------------------------------------------------");
        Log.i(TAG, "pending ws: onPreExecute");
        showLoadingDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "pending ws: doInBackground");
        //listDataParent = new ArrayList<Tn_Parent>();
        listPending();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i(TAG, "Call pending ws: onPostExecute");
        dismissLoadingDialog();

        //Log.i(TAG, "I am not up there "+status.toString());
        if(getContext()!=null) {
            //adapter = new Tn_ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), newList, selectAll);
            //listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            lvAdapter = new Tn_ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), lvList, selectAll);
            listView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
            // .............. below is not needed .....................
            //listAdapter = new Tn_ExpandableAdapter(listDataParent,getContext(), selectAll);
            //expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

And below is my dialogbox codes. The dialog work well in other class.

```
public void showLoadingDialog() {

    if (bar == null) {
        bar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        bar.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading_message));
        //bar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(getRetainInstance());
        bar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }
    bar.show();
}

public void dismissLoadingDialog() {

    if (bar != null && bar.isShowing()) {
        bar.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I really wish to know what are the problems. The dialog show up when I put showLoadingDialog() in the onCreateView(), but the problem is that the dialog will not dismiss if i put it inside the onCreateView(). Please help.

Comment: bar = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); here take the object of context and pass it in function and when you are calling it in async pass the context

Comment: Please search method for hide / show progress bar rather than asking question. You will get code snippet easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your **dismiss()** problem inside **onCreate**, try to change

```
public void dismissLoadingDialog() {
  if (bar != null && bar.isShowing()) {
      bar.dismiss();
  }
}
```

to

```
public void dismissLoadingDialog() {
  if (bar != null) {
      bar.dismiss();
      bar = null;
  }
}
```

The problem to not showing up your dialog inside **AsynTask** might be your **if (bar == null) {** condition, because at that time your **bar** object will not be null. So that the time when you are dismissing the dialog you have to initialize it to **null**. And please write **bar.show();** this line of code inside **if(...)** condition.

Comment: @HoeLuen sure, will wait for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

As **Preetika Kaur** suggested you should pass a `Context` object to you `showLoadingDialog()` and call `bar = new ProgressDialog(yourContextObject);` cause otherwise the bar would always be `null`.